# postgresql won't use index for character LIKE comparison during a nested loop

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I've two tables:

```
alpha

string1     | other_attr|
------------|-----------|
y-foo-one   | ...
y-foo-two   |
y-foo-three |
y-baz-one   |
y-bat-four  |
y-baz-two   |
```

```
beta

string2
---
foo
baz
bat
```

I would like to perform a fuzzy left join to get e.g.

```
string2 | string1     | other_attr |
--------|-------------|------------|
foo     | y-foo-one   | ...        |
foo     | y-foo-two   |          
foo     | y-foo-three |
baz     | y-baz-one   |
baz     | y-baz-two   |
bat     | y-bat-four  |
```

I have a btree index on `alpha(string1)`, so that the following query

```sql
SELECT * FROM alpha WHERE string1 LIKE 'y%';
```

uses a speedy index scan with the following condition:

```
Index Cond: (((string1)::text >= 'y'::text) AND ((string1)::text < 'z'::text))
```

However, when I try to write the nested loop query

```sql
SELECT * FROM beta LEFT JOIN alpha ON (alpha.string1 LIKE 'y-' || beta.string2 || '%')
```

PostgreSQL appears to refuse the index scan, instead forcing a seq scan as if it does not know that it can limit the search through all that text data to strings beginning with `y-`:

```
Join Filter: ((alpha.string1)::text ~~ (('y-'::text || (beta.string2)::text) || '%'::text))
```

This is rather a pain, as `alpha` has over a billion rows. Is there a better way to write the string comparison filter so it's clear to PostgreSQL that we know how `alpha.string1` should start, and that the wildcard only comes in at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it to use the index for the 'y-' part, but not for the rest.

```
SELECT * FROM beta LEFT JOIN alpha ON (alpha.string1 LIKE 'y-%' and alpha.string1 LIKE 'y-' || beta.string2 || '%')
```

To do better than that, I think you would need to loop over beta, issuing a query against alpha for each row.  I would probably do that on the client side, but you should also be able to wrap that into a table-returning function in a procedural language, with dynamic queries.  Or as Laurenz says, use a trigram index.

Answer (score 2):

The only option is to create a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON alpha USING gin (string1 gin_trgm_ops);
```

I admit that this is unfortunate, since the B-tree index would be smaller and more efficient.

The reason is that the string concatenation function is a black box to the optimizer, and it does not know that the resulting string will not start with a wildcard. Trigram indexes can also handle patterns that start with a wildcard.

Comment: Is it really a problem with the index type? My impression is that, if I manually executed the first SELECT statement in that question for each of the strings in `beta.string2` via a shell script or whatnot, it would use the index each time. However, because I am specifying the `LIKE` comparison using string concatenation, as part of a `JOIN` filter, the query analyzer doesn't appear to evaluate the string concatenation before deciding how it will run the query.

Comment: I don't thinknthat there would be a fundamental problem with using a B-tree index here, it is just that PostgreSQL is not smart enough to do that. I'll add some explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(alpha.string1 LIKE 'y-' || beta.string2 || '%')
```

Here the LIKE parameter is not a constant, rather it is the result of an expression evaluation. To use an index the planner would need to know the '%' is always at the end of the string, but I don't it does that kind of analysys on anything other than constants.

Since this works:

```
Index Cond: (((string1)::text >= 'y'::text) AND ((string1)::text < 'z'::text))
```

Why not just use it? If, say, string2 contains 'foo' you just have to come up with an expression or function that calculates the next text string in alphabetic order, like 'fop'. Then, LIKE 'y-foo%' becomes >='y-foo' AND < 'y-fop.'

Or course if the string ends with a 'z' it will be a bit more involved. But if it's just ASCII text with only contain alphanumeric characters, then...

```
\d foo
 Colonne |  Type   | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut
---------+---------+-----------------+-----------+------------
 id      | integer |                 | not null  |
 value   | text    |                 | not null  |
Index :
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_value" btree (value text_pattern_ops)

select value, left(value,char_length(value)-1)||chr(ascii(right(value,1))+1) from foo limit 10;
 value | ?column?
-------+----------
 y-1   | y-2
 y-2   | y-3
 y-3   | y-4
 y-4   | y-5
 y-5   | y-6
 y-6   | y-7
 y-7   | y-8
 y-8   | y-9
 y-9   | y-:
 y-10  | y-11
```

...seems to work...

```
 select * from foo join list on ((foo.value~>=~('y-'||list.l)) and (foo.value~<=~('y-'||left(list.l,char_length(list.l)-1)||chr(ascii(right(list.l,1))+1))));
                                                                                        Nested Loop  (cost=0.32..36968.41 rows=1122222 width=17) (actual time=0.052..0.770 rows=193 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on list  (cost=0.00..2.01 rows=101 width=6) (actual time=0.021..0.039 rows=101 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using foo_value on foo  (cost=0.32..254.89 rows=11111 width=11) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=101)
         Index Cond: ((value ~>=~ ('y-'::text || list.l)) AND (value ~<=~ (('y-'::text || "left"(list.l, (char_length(list.l) - 1))) || chr((ascii("right"(list.l, 1)) + 1)))))
 Planning Time: 0.166 ms
 Execution Time: 0.827 ms
```

...and we get the desired nested loop range index scan.

But really, the problem here is that there are several fields inside your column that represent different data and really want to be independent columns, so you can actually access them and search for them in the way you want.

So you could just create a bunch of GENERATED columns, for example using split_part() to split your a-b-c string into a, b, c ; then create an index on (a,b,c) and you can simply do:

```
WHERE a='y' AND b='foo'
```

This has the added bonus that b='foo' will not also select b='fooz' which would be selected by LIKE. Your question implies this might be what you actually want. If that's not the case, well, you'll still have to use LIKE and then that solution won't work, you have to build a range by hand like said above.